# CSS Top Property different between Internet Explorer and FireFox

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to search for this in stackoverflow but I couldn't find the answer.

Browsers I am using for testing:
Firefox 3.6.8
Internet Explorer 6.029

I am creating a box and positioning it via the position:absolute and top and left properties:

```
#testBox {
  top:10px;
  left:480px;
  width:220px;
  padding:3px;
  position:absolute;
  font-size:14px;
  text-align:center;
}

<div>
  <div>
  <span style="position:relative;">
    <span id="testBox">
    testtesttesttesttest<br />
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

What is happening is the "testBox" span is up further in IE than FireFox.  Is there something I can do to fix this problem?
Thanks,
Roy

Comment: Live fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tTcjS strangely enough, it displays the same effect as in IE6 in Chrome 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ie6, will be the problem, specifically the 6 part.

You will most likely need to define different rules in a different style sheet. Look into conditional statements: http://creativebits.org/webdev/ie_conditional_css

Also you can try using a css reset, it will make things easier down the line:
http://www.yahooapis.com/yui/3/cssreset/

Comment: @Pekka OP said unexpected behavior exists in ie6, so I assumed. Didn't even think issue could be in FF. My bad.

Comment: @hookedonwinter no actually, I seem to be wrong after all: It looks identical in IE6 and Chrome, but has no space in IE8 and FF. Seems to be a white space issue. That's *weird*! I stand corrected.

Comment: I've added a link to the yui reset, try adding that and then trying again. It will probably mess some of your old styling up, but in the long run it is definitely worth it

Comment: http://creativebits.org/webdev/ie_conditional_css is no longer, try https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a non-hackish method, but you can use conditional HTML (ie, a hack) to change top in IE6. Put this after your CSS, in the HTML.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
            #testBox {
               top: 20px; // or whatever
            }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```